# How to split csv comma separated value as single row in a new column using pyspark

Tags: excel, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a log file in csv which has a column contains a list of filepaths separated by comma. I want to split those filepaths into new rows using pyspark(or excel). This original data looks like:

```
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|time      |message                                                                     |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|4-19 20:00|[info] Delete object in ['03-26/abc/123.jpg', '03-26/abc/456.jpg']          |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|4-19 21:00|[info] Delete object in ['03-27/def/789.jpg', '03-27/def/012.jpg']          |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd like it to be converted as this:

```
+-----------------+
|path             |
+-----------------+
|03-26/abc/123.jpg|
+-----------------+
|03-26/abc/456.jpg|
+-----------------+
|03-27/def/789.jpg|
+-----------------+
|03-27/def/012.jpg|
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just extract those paths from `message` and parse it

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .withColumn('paths', F.explode(F.from_json(F.regexp_extract('message', '\[\'[^\]]+]', 0), 'array<string>')))
    .show(10, False)
)

+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|time      |message                                                           |paths            |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|4-19 20:00|[info] Delete object in ['03-26/abc/123.jpg', '03-26/abc/456.jpg']|03-26/abc/123.jpg|
|4-19 20:00|[info] Delete object in ['03-26/abc/123.jpg', '03-26/abc/456.jpg']|03-26/abc/456.jpg|
|4-19 21:00|[info] Delete object in ['03-27/def/789.jpg', '03-27/def/012.jpg']|03-27/def/789.jpg|
|4-19 21:00|[info] Delete object in ['03-27/def/789.jpg', '03-27/def/012.jpg']|03-27/def/012.jpg|
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```